# org-habit - do a repetitive task certain days of the week only?

Tags: org-mode, org-habit

I want to know how can I set a repetitive task for only a range of days of the week, for instance from Monday to Friday only.

Comment: AFAIK, org-habit has no support for restricting to certain days of week only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This special sexp diary entry will repeat the TODO on weekdays:

```
** TODO On Weekdays
<%%(let ((dayname (calendar-day-of-week date)))(memq dayname '(1 2 3 4 5)))> [2015-02-01 So]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly.  While it does cause the event to display in the agenda on weekdays, it doesn't work correctly with the repeating-todo functionality.  When I mark the task as DONE, it doesn't return to the TODO state.

Comment: The diary sexps are not meant to work with rescheduling. If you depend on this, it's probably easier to set up multiple todo entries, one per weekday.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused: assuming a TODO entry will be marked DONE when it's done, how is a repeating sexp useful if it doesn't cause the TODO to get rescheduled?

Comment: Citing the Org-mode manual: "the use of diary sexp entries like `<%%(diary-float t 42)>` in scheduling and deadline timestamps is limited. [...] However, it will show the item on each day where the sexp entry matches".

Comment: I suppose, then, that you could use an agenda view that displays DONE items, and then manually mark it TODO and then DONE again.  Too bad that the sexps can't just work with repeating items.  :(

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/oddious/org-habit-plus

> **What’s this?**
>
> The great org-habit module lacks a way to handle a very common type of
>   habits, those that can/may/must be executed only on certain weekdays.
>   There exist several workarounds like creating a habit for each day of
>   interest, but they are less flexible and spoil the beauty of Org.
>
> This little enhancement aims to fill the gap. It’s a fork of the
>   original org-habit module and most of the internals are left
>   untouched.
>
> **What works**
>
> The desired minimum.

...

> **How it works**
>
> As simple as specifying the weekdays (1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday, space
>   separated), on which a habit is expected to be performed, in the
>   :HABIT_WEEKDAYS: property.
>
> **WARNING!!!**
>
> Expect consistent behaviour only for “.+”-style habits. The “+”- and
>   “++”-style habits are better, at least for now, to be used the
>   original way.

Answer (score 2):

I was currently searching for the same functionality and came across this solution from [org-mode FAQ](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#orgaedcaba)

```
** Daily meeting
   <%%(memq (calendar-day-of-week date) '(1 2 3 4 5))>
```

It works for me. I am using Emacs 27.1 on Debian 11.

Answer (score 0):

Make a repeating entry for Monday and then use Org's timeshift to create additional entries for Tuesday to Friday.

Comment: Humm... could you expand your answer with an example? Thank you!

Comment: @shackra For anybody still wondering, I think what he meant is just to create like five entries with the same name in parallel, just with different scheduled times. e.g. this one: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26610/multiple-scheduled-timestamps-for-one-task/26753